# Is there a way to re-enable name mangling after using extern 'C'?

Tags: c++, c

Lets say I have a c++ header file that looks like this:

```
/* cpp_header.h */
#include <vector>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern 'C' {
#endif
void foo1(int x);
void foo2(int y);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
/* function I don't want visible to C compiler */
void foo3(vector<int> &v);
#endif
```

Now I include this header file into a C header file:

```
/* c_header.h - all implementation built with C compiler */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cpp_header.h"

int cfoo();
int cfoo1(int x);
```

Now lets say I want to use cfoo() and cfoo1() in another cpp file and i do something like this:

```
/* crazy.cpp - this will cause a build breakage */
extern 'C' {
#include "c_header.h"
}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   cfoo();
   cfoo1(88);
   std::cout << "Yes, this is crazy!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

The code above will never build because 'foo3()' in the first header file will complain that we are trying to build a template with C-linkage. This happen because we wrapped the entire c_header.h file within a 'extern C' guard. Is there a way I can add something that can reverse the 'extern C' guard so that foo3 will be built with C++ linkage. Maybe something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern 'CPP' {  /* re-enable C++ name-mangling/linkage */
   foo3(vector<int> &v);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, there is `extern "C++"`. But why are you wrapping the header include in `extern "C"` in the first place?

Comment: The `extern "C"` should only wrap declarations *intended to have C linkage*. I.e., your `c_header.h` should look like your `cpp_header.h` (with the `#ifdef __cplusplus` -- `extern "C"`) to ensure a C++ compiler sees *C* functions; your `cpp_header.h` should have nothing of the sort (because it's C++), and you should not have any `extern "C"` in your main.cpp (because it's up to the headers to handle this stuff internally).

Comment: You could include cpp_header directly without the `extern "C"` before you include c_header, assuming you have guards or some other mechanism to make this work.

Comment: Doesn't extern require string literal? `extern 'C'` is likely invalid and should be `extern "C"`.

Comment: The format of `extern` is `extern string-literal`. `"C"` is string literal, `'C'` is not

Comment: @Aconcagua: If it's a C++ header, by definition it *doesn't* expose functions with C interface. (It would be a C header, then, or an example of *extremly* poor design -- exposing C interface in a header that cannot be used by a C compiler?)

Comment: @Aconcagua: I have no idea what you are talking about. A C lib that wants its headers useable by C++ wraps its headers in `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `extern "C"`. A C++ lib that wants to be useable by C does the same for the C headers (but might have C++-specific headers as well). *Mixing* C and C++ declarations in the same header serves no practical purpose as it would only be useable by C++ anyway. (You would have to have that *C* header around somewhere anyway, and would just duplicate its contents...)

Comment: @DevSolar Just let's forget it... All seems to be a matter of different definitions about what is what...

Comment: @T.C. - Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for. Long story short, someone put a C++ header-file into a C-header file. Said C-header file is compiled inside a CPP source file wrapped around a extern 'C' guard. This wasn't a problem because the C++ header file only had C-style APIs and was also guarded with #ifdef__cplusplus and extern 'c'. The problem started when I wanted to add a API that had C++ feature (ie: void foo(vector<int> &v) into the C++ header file. I recommended we do things properly but fixing the code will take time. 

*sorry about the formatting*

Answer (score 11):

As explained in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage, you can use both `extern "C"` and `extern "C++"` (the latter being the default for C++).

It also says

> When language specifications nest, the innermost specification is the one that is in effect.

So

```
extern "C" {
    extern "C++" void foo3(vector<int> &v);
}
```

should work fine.

That said, a better solution would be to add the `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `extern "C" {` parts to the declarations in the C header itself. Then you don't need to wrap the `#include` in your main cpp file.

As in:

```
/* c_header.h - all implementation built with C compiler */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cpp_header.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int cfoo();
int cfoo1(int x);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then all consumers can just `#include "c_header.h"`, no matter whether they're in C++ or C.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what I was looking for.